# Building a shared library that includes the symbols of another shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have 2 shared libraries: `lib1.so` and `lib2.so`.
I want to build a new shared library that uses symbols from both lib1 and lib2. The new shared library depends on `lib1` and `lib2`. So, I have to set my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to their paths at run-time.
Is there a way to make the new created library contain all the symbols in `lib1.so` at compile/link time?
I want my new created library to depend on `lib2.so` only at run time. (so the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will contain the path of `lib2.so` only)

Comment: You can build lib1 as a static library.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the source code of lib1.so and lib2.so

Comment: If you can't get the source then you're likely out of luck.